# netaddr network ID of subnets

Tags: python, networking

I'd like to use `netaddr` to find out starting addresses of subnets (network IDs) for a given address.

Example input: `192.168.1.130/26`

Example output: `192.168.1.0 192.168.1.64 192.168.1.128 192.168.1.192`

So far I've tried using this code:

```
from netaddr import *

ip = IPNetwork('192.168.1.130/26')
subnets = list(ip.subnet(26))
print(subnets)
[IPNetwork('192.168.1.128/26')]
```

It shows the correct network ID, but only for that SPECIFIC address, not all the subnet's network IDs.

Can I somehow alter this code to show me all four network IDs in this case (it should be able to work with any IP/mask)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to divide a /24 network into 4 /26 network, or divide a /26 network into 4 /28 subnets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from netaddr import *
>>>
>>> ip = IPNetwork('192.168.1.130/26')
>>> supernet = ip.supernet(24)[0]
>>> print list(supernet.subnet(26))
[IPNetwork('192.168.1.0/26'), IPNetwork('192.168.1.64/26'), IPNetwork('192.168.1.128/26'), IPNetwork('192.168.1.192/26')]
```

Comment: Omg...its SUPERNETTING, not subnetting. Thank you.